# How is the spring boot application affected by the maven dependencies?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I am just wondering if there is any good practice when it comes to maven dependencies.
I am developing a small spring boot application and i am using multiple dependencies:
-Lombok
-Guava
-Spring Security
- Postgresql
-jsonwebtoken for Tokens
and some other spring boots dep...

My question is how much are these dependencies are going to affect my application?
Is it too much to have them when it comes to performance?

Comment: To be honest I really don't understand your question. If you add a dependency you have the code which is usually used by your own application. If you don't use the code just remove the dependency. What exactly do you mean by "performance" here?

Comment: I mean, does it matter if i develop a small application which uses 15 different dependencies? Does it affect the application?

Comment: I got you @FazliZekiqi
Depends on the dependencies and that may affect the performance or/and only the jar/war/ear size.

Comment: Can you develop you answer? In which way and what kind of dependencies does affect the performance?

Comment: Have a ton of dependencies which can affect the performance or obliging extra configuration. I can't list them.

Comment: It effects only your application if you use those dependencies which means if you use the code of the dependencies. Calling frameworks etc. For example guava... Otherwise it's only waster of some memory. I would reconsider the usage of dependencies. For example guava? For what purpose? Lombok?

Comment: @JoãoZarate Thank you!

Comment: @khmarbaise that is exactly why I asked the question. I use more or less 5 Guava classes. I could implement those methods by myself.
Then Lombok also, i only use getters, setters, allargsco.. etc ...!
I can generate them by myself!
Therefore, I wondered in what way can these dependencies that I barely use affect my application when deploying

Comment: @FazliZekiqi, no problem! To help to leave dependencies in that you don't need anymore, I put a answer for this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply referenced in comment:

To help you and only be used to supplement the information. If you feel worried concerning too many libraries, you can use the [Maven Dependency Analyzer tool](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html).

**Only depend on things you need**

"*It's really easy to leave dependencies in that you don't need anymore.  It's hard to figure out if a dependency is still valid. Fortunately, there's a tool for that- The Maven Dependency Analyzer. If you stick this into your build it will log out to tell you exactly which dependencies you've got which you don't need, along with dependencies you need that you haven't explicitly got (and are liable to cause your system to break if your dependencies change).*"

Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/kill-your-dependencies-javamaven-edition